# Why when I used multi-thread, the music could be still played, but the display of a moving score was gone?

Tags: java, multithreading, wav

I want to show a moving score on screen and simultaneously play its corresponding music so that the user can read the music score without page turning and hear the music along with the moving score. When I display the moving score alone in Test7.java, and when I play the music alone in Tes11.java, both of them are working fine. But when I used multi-thread to combine them in Test21.java, only the music played but the moving score was not shown at all. Test7.java, Test11.java, and Test21.java are listed below:

```
//Test7.java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import java.io.*;
import sun.audio.*;
import java.io.IOException; 

class MyPanel extends JPanel{   
    int x[] = new int[59]; 
    int y[] = new int[59]; 
    int width[] = new int[59];
    int height = 20;
    Color color[] = new Color[59];//the color of each note

    //一根紫 竹 直 苗 苗,      5  ĺ  65 3 │ 52 32 1 ─ 
    //送給寶寶做管 簫,      6 ĺ   3 5  6 3 │5 ─ ─ ─
    //簫兒對準口,            ĺ 6 3 6 5 ─ 
    //口兒對準簫,           6 5 3 6  5 ─
    //簫 中吹 出  新 時 調, 56  ĺ  65 3 │ 52 32 1 ─
    //小寶寶, 小寶 寶,      1 13 2 ─  | 1 13 2  ─   
    //咿底 咿底學會了.啊～～  6 ĺ   6  ĺ  2 6 | 5 . 6  23 56│ 5 ─ ─ ─

    String[] lyric = {"一", " 根", "紫～", "竹", "直～", "苗～", "苗,", "送", "給", "寶", "寶", "做", "管", "簫,",
                      "簫", "兒", "對", "準", "口,", "口", "兒", "對", "準", "簫,", 
                      "簫～", "中", "吹～", "出", "新～", "時～ ", "調,",
                      "小", "寶～", "寶,", "小", "寶～", "寶,", 
                      "咿", "底", "咿", "底", "學 ", "會", "了,", "啊 ～     ～    ～"};//共45個

    int[] numNotes = {1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1,
                      1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6};//共45個

    int[][] notes = {{5,2},{8,2},{6,1},{5,1},{3,2},{5,1},{2,1},{3,1},{2,1},{1,4},{6,1},{8,1},
                     {3,1},{5,1},{6,2},{3,2},{5,8},{8,1},{6,1},{3,1},{6,1},{5,4},{6,1},{8,1},
                     {3,1},{6,1},{5,4},{5,1},{6,1},{8,2},{6,1},{5,1},{3,2},{5,1},{2,1},{3,1},
                     {2,1},{1,4},{1,2},{1,1},{3,1},{2,4},{1,2},{1,1},{3,1},{2,4},{6,1},{8,1},
                     {6,1},{8,1},{9,2},{6,2},{5,3},{6,1},{2,1},{3,1},{5,1},{6,1},{5,8}};//共59個

    String[] simplifiedNote = {"| 5", "  1", " 6", "5", "3", "| 5", "2", "3", "2", "1  - ", "| 6", "1", 
                               "3", "5", "6", " 3", " 5  -  -  -", "| 1", "6", "3", "6", "5  - ", "| 6", "1", 
                               "3", "6", "5  -", "| 5", "6", "1", "6", "5", " 3", "| 5", "2", "3",
                               "2", "1   -", "| 1", "1", "3", "2   -", "| 1", "1", "3", "2  -", "| 6", "1", 
                               "6", "1", "2", "6", "| 5   .", "6", "2", "3", "5", "6", "| 5  -  -  - "};//共59個

    Color color0 = new Color(255,255,255); //白色 
    Color color1 = new Color(255,0,0); //紅色
    Color color2 = new Color(255,165,0); //橙色
    Color color3 = new Color(255,255,0); //黃色
    Color color4 = new Color(0,128,0); //綠色
    Color color5 = new Color(0,0,255); //藍色
    Color color6 = new Color(75,0,130); //靛色
    Color color7 = new Color(100,0,153); //紫色
    Color color8 = new Color(153,0,0); //暗紅
    Color color9 = new Color(0,0,0); //黑色
    Color color10 = new Color(37,255,255); //淺藍

    public void display(){
        for (int i = 0;i < notes.length; i++) {
            //System.out.println("notes[" + i + "][0] = " + notes[i][0]);
            switch (notes[i][0]) {
                case 1:
                     y[i] = 400;
                     color[i] = color1;
                     break;
                case 2:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20;
                     color[i] = color2;
                     break;
                case 3:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*2;
                     color[i] = color3;
                     break;
                case 4:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*3;
                     color[i] = color4;
                     break;
                case 5:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*4;
                     color[i] = color5;
                     break;
                case 6:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*5;
                     color[i] = color6;
                     break;
                case 7:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*6;
                     color[i] = color7;
                     break;
                case 8:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*7;
                     color[i] = color1;
                     break;
                case 9:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*8;
                     color[i] = color2;
            }

            switch (notes[i][1]) {
                case 1: width[i] = 20;     
                        break;
                case 2: width[i] = 20 * 2; 
                        break;
                case 3: width[i] = 20 * 3; 
                        break;
                case 4: width[i] = 20 * 4; 
                        break;
                case 5: width[i] = 20 * 5; 
                        break;
                case 6: width[i] = 20 * 6; 
                        break;
                case 7: width[i] = 20 * 7; 
                        break;
                case 8: width[i] = 20 * 8;
            }
        }

        x[0] = 100;
        for (int i = 1; i < notes.length; i++){
             x[i] = x[i-1] + width[i-1];
        }



int timeLast = 0;
        //timeLast = total executing time
        while(timeLast < 900){ 
            for (int i = 0; i < notes.length; i ++){
                x[i]--;
            }
            this.repaint(); 
            try {Thread.sleep(55);}
            catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            timeLast = timeLast + 1; 
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g); 
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

        g2d.setColor(color9); 
        g2d.setFont(new Font("新細明體", Font.BOLD, 20));

        int y1 = 130; //C調 4/4 Y坐標
        int y2 = 180; //簡譜行Y坐標
        int y3 = 210; //歌詞行Y坐標
        int y4 = 163; //加高音點
        int y5 = 180; //加八分音符底線
        int y6 = 470;  //色彩音符說明

        int chrPosition = 0;
        g2d.drawString("C調  4/4", 16, y1);

        //色彩音符說明
        g2d.drawString("色彩音符：", 16, y6);
        g2d.setColor(color1);

        g2d.fillRoundRect(126, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(": Do", 150, y6);//126 + 24
        g2d.setColor(color2);
        g2d.fillRoundRect(206, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);//150 + 56
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(": Re", 230, y6);//206 + 24
        g2d.setColor(color3);
        g2d.fillRoundRect(286, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);//230 + 56
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(": Mi", 310, y6);//286 + 24
        g2d.setColor(color4);
        g2d.fillRoundRect(366, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);//310 + 56
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(": Fa",390, y6);//366 + 24
        g2d.setColor(color5);
        g2d.fillRoundRect(446, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);//390 + 56
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(": So", 470, y6);//446 + 24
        g2d.setColor(color6);
        g2d.fillRoundRect(526, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);//470 + 56
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(": La", 550, y6);//526 + 24
        //g2d.setColor(color7);
        //g2d.fillRoundRect(606, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);//550 + 56
        //g2d.setColor(color9);
        //g2d.drawString(":Si", 630, y6);//606 + 24

        //寫出簡譜
        for (int i = 0;i < simplifiedNote.length; i++){

            g2d.drawString(simplifiedNote[i], x[i], y2);
        }

        //在簡譜下方寫出歌詞
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        for (int i = 0;  i < lyric.length; i++){
            if (i != 0 && numNotes[i-1] == 2) {
                chrPosition = chrPosition + 1;
                g2d.drawString(lyric[i], x[chrPosition], y3);
            }
            else {
                g2d.drawString(lyric[i], x[chrPosition], y3);
            }
            chrPosition = chrPosition + 1;
        }


        //在簡譜上方加高音點
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[1]+14, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[11]+2, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[17]+11, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[23]+2, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[29]+2, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[47]+2, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[49]+2, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[50]+2, y4);

        //在簡譜下方加八分音符底線
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[2]+4, y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[3], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[5]+8, y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[6], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[7], y5);//5
        g2d.drawString("_", x[8], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[10]+8, y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[11], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[12], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[13], y5);//10
        g2d.drawString("_", x[17]+8, y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[18], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[19], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[20], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[22]+8, y5);//15
        g2d.drawString("_", x[23], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[24], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[25], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[27]+8, y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[28], y5);//20
        g2d.drawString("_", x[30], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[31], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[33]+8, y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[34], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[35], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[36], y5);//25
        g2d.drawString("_", x[39], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[40], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[43], y5);//1
        g2d.drawString("_", x[44], y5);//3
        g2d.drawString("_", x[46]+8, y5);//6
        g2d.drawString("_", x[47], y5);//1
        g2d.drawString("_", x[48], y5);//6
        g2d.drawString("_", x[49], y5);//1
        g2d.drawString("_", x[53], y5);//6
        g2d.drawString("_", x[54], y5);//2
        g2d.drawString("_", x[55], y5);//3
        g2d.drawString("_", x[56], y5);//5
        g2d.drawString("_", x[57], y5);//6

        //在歌詞下方繪出彩色譜        
        for (int i = 0;i < notes.length; i++){

            g2d.setColor(color[i]);
            g2d.fillRoundRect(x[i], y[i], width[i], height, 3,3); //畫圓角方塊

            g2d.setColor(color8);
            g2d.drawLine(x[i],230, x[i]+width[i], 230);//畫水平上線

            g2d.setColor(color8);
            g2d.drawLine(x[i],231, x[i], 429);//畫直紅線

            g2d.setColor(color8);
            g2d.drawLine(x[i],430, x[i]+width[i], 430);//畫水平下線
        }
        g2d.setColor(color8);
        g2d.drawLine(x[notes.length-1]+ width[notes.length - 1],231, x[notes.length - 1] + width[notes.length - 1],429);//畫邊界直紅線
    }
}

public class Test7 {
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException
    {
        JFrame  jf = new JFrame("康樂彩歌");        
        MyPanel jp = new MyPanel();
        //jp.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

        jp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        jf.setBounds(0, 0, 1368, 730);      
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("選歌：");    //創建標簽
        label1.setFont(new Font("新細明體", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        JComboBox cmbox = new JComboBox();    //創建JComboBox
        //cmb.setLocation(500,500);
        cmbox.setFont(new Font("新細明體", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        //cmb.setBounds(120,80,150,30);

        cmbox.addItem("紫竹調");
        cmbox.addItem("走一同去郊遊");
        cmbox.addItem("大野狼");
        cmbox.addItem("歸來吧蘇連多");
        cmbox.addItem("追尋");
        cmbox.addItem("三輪車");
        cmbox.addItem("我家門前有小河");
        cmbox.addItem("漁家樂");
        cmbox.addItem("嚕啦啦");
        cmbox.addItem("踏雪尋梅");

        JRadioButton rb2 = new JRadioButton("加人聲", false);
        rb2.setFont(new Font("新細明體", Font.PLAIN, 20));

        JButton btPlay = new JButton("PLAY");
        btPlay.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG_INPUT, Font.BOLD, 25));

        JButton btStop = new JButton("STOP");
        btStop.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG_INPUT, Font.BOLD, 25));

        JButton btContinue = new JButton("CONTINUE");
        btContinue.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG_INPUT, Font.BOLD, 25));

        jp.add(label1);
        jp.add(cmbox);
        //jp.add(rb1);
        jp.add(rb2);
        jp.add(btPlay);
        jp.add(btStop);
        jp.add(btContinue);

        btPlay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {//给按钮添加事件接收器
               @Override
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {//接受到事件后,进行下面的处理
                //System.out.println("Hello World");// 控制台打印输出
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello World");// 弹出对话框,显示Hello World
               }
              });

        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.add(jp); 

        //AudioTest au1 = new AudioTest();
        //au1.AudioPlay();
        jp.display();
    }
}

//Test11.java
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

class AudioTest {
//This class is used to play a section of 1 minute long music
    public void AudioPlay() {

        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

        try{
          Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
          AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("audio1.wav"));

              clip.open(inputStream);
              clip.start();
              while (!clip.isRunning())
                  Thread.sleep(10);
              while (clip.isRunning())
                  Thread.sleep(10);
              clip.close();
            } catch (Exception e)
                {
                  e.printStackTrace(); 
                  System.out.println(e); 
                }
        System.out.println("done"); //to see if the sound is finished playing
    } 
}
public class Test11 {

    public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException
    {
        AudioTest au1 = new AudioTest();
        au1.AudioPlay();
    }

}

//Test21.java
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import java.io.*;
import sun.audio.*;

class AudioTest {
//This class is used to play a section of 1 minute long music
    public void AudioPlay() {

        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

        try{
          Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
          AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("audio1.wav"));

              clip.open(inputStream);
              clip.start();
              while (!clip.isRunning())
                  Thread.sleep(0);
              while (clip.isRunning())
                  Thread.sleep(0);
              clip.close();
            } catch (Exception e)
                {
                  e.printStackTrace(); 
                  System.out.println(e); 
                }
        System.out.println("done"); 
    } 
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel{   
    int x[] = new int[59]; 
    int y[] = new int[59]; 
    int width[] = new int[59];
    int height = 20;
    Color color[] = new Color[59];//the color of each note

    //一根紫 竹 直 苗 苗,      5  ĺ  65 3 │ 52 32 1 ─ 
    //送給寶寶做管 簫,      6 ĺ   3 5  6 3 │5 ─ ─ ─
    //簫兒對準口,            ĺ 6 3 6 5 ─ 
    //口兒對準簫,           6 5 3 6  5 ─
    //簫 中吹 出  新 時 調, 56  ĺ  65 3 │ 52 32 1 ─
    //小寶寶, 小寶 寶,      1 13 2 ─  | 1 13 2  ─   
    //咿底 咿底學會了.啊～～  6 ĺ   6  ĺ  2 6 | 5 . 6  23 56│ 5 ─ ─ ─

    String[] lyric = {"一", " 根", "紫～", "竹", "直～", "苗～", "苗,", "送", "給", "寶", "寶", "做", "管", "簫,",
                      "簫", "兒", "對", "準", "口,", "口", "兒", "對", "準", "簫,", 
                      "簫～", "中", "吹～", "出", "新～", "時～ ", "調,",
                      "小", "寶～", "寶,", "小", "寶～", "寶,", 
                      "咿", "底", "咿", "底", "學 ", "會", "了,", "啊 ～     ～    ～"};//共45個

    int[] numNotes = {1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1,
                      1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6};//共45個

    int[][] notes = {{5,2},{8,2},{6,1},{5,1},{3,2},{5,1},{2,1},{3,1},{2,1},{1,4},{6,1},{8,1},
                     {3,1},{5,1},{6,2},{3,2},{5,8},{8,1},{6,1},{3,1},{6,1},{5,4},{6,1},{8,1},
                     {3,1},{6,1},{5,4},{5,1},{6,1},{8,2},{6,1},{5,1},{3,2},{5,1},{2,1},{3,1},
                     {2,1},{1,4},{1,2},{1,1},{3,1},{2,4},{1,2},{1,1},{3,1},{2,4},{6,1},{8,1},
                     {6,1},{8,1},{9,2},{6,2},{5,3},{6,1},{2,1},{3,1},{5,1},{6,1},{5,8}};//共59個

    String[] simplifiedNote = {"| 5", "  1", " 6", "5", "3", "| 5", "2", "3", "2", "1  - ", "| 6", "1", 
                               "3", "5", "6", " 3", " 5  -  -  -", "| 1", "6", "3", "6", "5  - ", "| 6", "1", 
                               "3", "6", "5  -", "| 5", "6", "1", "6", "5", " 3", "| 5", "2", "3",
                               "2", "1   -", "| 1", "1", "3", "2   -", "| 1", "1", "3", "2  -", "| 6", "1", 
                               "6", "1", "2", "6", "| 5   .", "6", "2", "3", "5", "6", "| 5  -  -  - "};//共59個

    Color color0 = new Color(255,255,255); //白色 
    Color color1 = new Color(255,0,0); //紅色
    Color color2 = new Color(255,165,0); //橙色
    Color color3 = new Color(255,255,0); //黃色
    Color color4 = new Color(0,128,0); //綠色
    Color color5 = new Color(0,0,255); //藍色
    Color color6 = new Color(75,0,130); //靛色
    Color color7 = new Color(100,0,153); //紫色
    Color color8 = new Color(153,0,0); //暗紅
    Color color9 = new Color(0,0,0); //黑色
    Color color10 = new Color(37,255,255); //淺藍

    public void display(){
        for (int i = 0;i < notes.length; i++) {
            //System.out.println("notes[" + i + "][0] = " + notes[i][0]);
            switch (notes[i][0]) {
                case 1:
                     y[i] = 400;
                     color[i] = color1;
                     break;
                case 2:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20;
                     color[i] = color2;
                     break;
                case 3:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*2;
                     color[i] = color3;
                     break;
                case 4:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*3;
                     color[i] = color4;
                     break;
                case 5:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*4;
                     color[i] = color5;
                     break;
                case 6:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*5;
                     color[i] = color6;
                     break;
                case 7:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*6;
                     color[i] = color7;
                     break;
                case 8:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*7;
                     color[i] = color1;
                     break;
                case 9:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*8;
                     color[i] = color2;
            }

            switch (notes[i][1]) {
                case 1: width[i] = 20;     
                        break;
                case 2: width[i] = 20 * 2; 
                        break;
                case 3: width[i] = 20 * 3; 
                        break;
                case 4: width[i] = 20 * 4; 
                        break;
                case 5: width[i] = 20 * 5; 
                        break;
                case 6: width[i] = 20 * 6; 
                        break;
                case 7: width[i] = 20 * 7; 
                        break;
                case 8: width[i] = 20 * 8;
            }
        }

        x[0] = 100;
        for (int i = 1; i < notes.length; i++){
             x[i] = x[i-1] + width[i-1];
        }



        int timeLast = 0; //total executing time

        while(timeLast < 900){ 
            for (int i = 0; i < notes.length; i ++){
                x[i]--;
            }
            this.repaint(); 
            try {Thread.sleep(10);}
            catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            timeLast = timeLast + 1; 
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g); 
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

        g2d.setColor(color9); 
        g2d.setFont(new Font("新細明體", Font.BOLD, 20));

        int y1 = 130; //C調 4/4 Y坐標
        int y2 = 180; //簡譜行Y坐標
        int y3 = 210; //歌詞行Y坐標
        int y4 = 163; //加高音點
        int y5 = 180; //加八分音符底線
        int y6 = 470;  //色彩音符說明

        int chrPosition = 0;
        g2d.drawString("C調  4/4", 16, y1);

        //色彩音符說明
        g2d.drawString("色彩音符：", 16, y6);
        g2d.setColor(color1);

        g2d.fillRoundRect(126, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(": Do", 150, y6);//126 + 24
        g2d.setColor(color2);
        g2d.fillRoundRect(206, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);//150 + 56
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(": Re", 230, y6);//206 + 24
        g2d.setColor(color3);
        g2d.fillRoundRect(286, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);//230 + 56
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(": Mi", 310, y6);//286 + 24
        g2d.setColor(color4);
        g2d.fillRoundRect(366, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);//310 + 56
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(": Fa",390, y6);//366 + 24
        g2d.setColor(color5);
        g2d.fillRoundRect(446, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);//390 + 56
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(": So", 470, y6);//446 + 24
        g2d.setColor(color6);
        g2d.fillRoundRect(526, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);//470 + 56
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(": La", 550, y6);//526 + 24
        //g2d.setColor(color7);
        //g2d.fillRoundRect(606, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);//550 + 56
        //g2d.setColor(color9);
        //g2d.drawString(":Si", 630, y6);//606 + 24

        //寫出簡譜
        for (int i = 0;i < simplifiedNote.length; i++){

            g2d.drawString(simplifiedNote[i], x[i], y2);
        }

        //在簡譜下方寫出歌詞
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        for (int i = 0;  i < lyric.length; i++){
            if (i != 0 && numNotes[i-1] == 2) {
                chrPosition = chrPosition + 1;
                g2d.drawString(lyric[i], x[chrPosition], y3);
            }
            else {
                g2d.drawString(lyric[i], x[chrPosition], y3);
            }
            chrPosition = chrPosition + 1;
        }


        //在簡譜上方加高音點
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[1]+14, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[11]+2, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[17]+11, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[23]+2, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[29]+2, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[47]+2, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[49]+2, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[50]+2, y4);

        //在簡譜下方加八分音符底線
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[2]+4, y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[3], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[5]+8, y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[6], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[7], y5);//5
        g2d.drawString("_", x[8], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[10]+8, y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[11], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[12], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[13], y5);//10
        g2d.drawString("_", x[17]+8, y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[18], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[19], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[20], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[22]+8, y5);//15
        g2d.drawString("_", x[23], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[24], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[25], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[27]+8, y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[28], y5);//20
        g2d.drawString("_", x[30], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[31], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[33]+8, y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[34], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[35], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[36], y5);//25
        g2d.drawString("_", x[39], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[40], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[43], y5);//1
        g2d.drawString("_", x[44], y5);//3
        g2d.drawString("_", x[46]+8, y5);//6
        g2d.drawString("_", x[47], y5);//1
        g2d.drawString("_", x[48], y5);//6
        g2d.drawString("_", x[49], y5);//1
        g2d.drawString("_", x[53], y5);//6
        g2d.drawString("_", x[54], y5);//2
        g2d.drawString("_", x[55], y5);//3
        g2d.drawString("_", x[56], y5);//5
        g2d.drawString("_", x[57], y5);//6

        //在歌詞下方繪出彩色譜        
        for (int i = 0;i < notes.length; i++){

            g2d.setColor(color[i]);
            g2d.fillRoundRect(x[i], y[i], width[i], height, 3,3); //畫圓角方塊

            g2d.setColor(color8);
            g2d.drawLine(x[i],230, x[i]+width[i], 230);//畫水平上線

            g2d.setColor(color8);
            g2d.drawLine(x[i],231, x[i], 429);//畫直紅線

            g2d.setColor(color8);
            g2d.drawLine(x[i],430, x[i]+width[i], 430);//畫水平下線
        }
        g2d.setColor(color8);
        g2d.drawLine(x[notes.length-1]+ width[notes.length - 1],231, x[notes.length - 1] + width[notes.length - 1],429);//畫邊界直紅線
    }
}

 public class Test21 implements Runnable {
    private Thread t;
    private String threadName;

    Test21(String name) {
          threadName = name;
          System.out.println("Creating " +  threadName );
       }

    AudioTest au1 = new AudioTest();
    MyPanel panel1 = new MyPanel();

    public void run() {

        try {
            //jp.display();
            if (au1!=null) {au1.AudioPlay();}
            if (panel1!=null) {panel1.display();}
        } finally {}
        //System.out.println(threadName + " exiting.");
     }

     public void start () {
        System.out.println("Starting " +  threadName );
        if (t == null) {
           t = new Thread (this, threadName);
           t.start ();
        }
     }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test21 R1 = new Test21( "Thread-1");
        R1.start();

        Test21 R2 = new Test21( "Thread-2");
        R2.start();

    }
}
```

Please kindly help me! I have tried to solve this problem for months. May be it's about the logic problem in multi-threading. Thank you so much!:)

Answer (score 0):

*I've written the answer asuming that the code regarding audio and visuals is working properly.*

---

Looking at the code related to threading (after a bit of formatting), i.e.

```java
public class Test21 implements Runnable {
    private Thread t;
    private String threadName;

    AudioTest au1 = new AudioTest();
    MyPanel panel1 = new MyPanel();

    Test21(String name) {
        threadName = name;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            //jp.display();
            if (au1!=null) {au1.AudioPlay();}
            if (panel1!=null) {panel1.display();}
        } finally {}
    }

    public void start () {
        System.out.println("Starting " +  threadName );
        if (t == null) {
            t = new Thread (this, threadName);
            t.start ();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test21 R1 = new Test21( "Thread-1");
        R1.start();
        Test21 R2 = new Test21( "Thread-2");
        R2.start();
    }
}
```

I've noticed that most of the code you've written here is not adding any logic. The thread `t` and the method `start` seem redundant to me. Another thing is that the interface `Runnable` acts as a wrapper for code that can be given to a thread to execute. You don't need to add any custom logic regarding threading to that. Just use it straight forward as a wrapper.

The key mistake done is that you are using a single `Runnable` implementation to execute two different things parallel. The method `run` is implemented as follows:

```java
    public void run() {
        try {
            //jp.display();
            if (au1!=null) {au1.AudioPlay();}
            if (panel1!=null) {panel1.display();}
        } finally {}
    }
```

This is unfortunately wrong because the generated threads from this class are going to play the audio and then display the panel sequencially. In your `main` method you actually just start two thread where each is just playing the audio and shows the panel afterwards.

What you need is a thread `t1` that plays the audio and a thread `t2` that shows the visual stuff. Both are oneline-statements that can be put in an anonymous `Runnable`. It could look like as follows.

```java
public class Test21 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create and start the thread that plays the audio.
        new Thread(() -> {
            new AudioTest().AudioPlay();
        }).start();

        // Create and start the thread that shows the visualls.
        new Thread(() -> {
            new MyPanel().display();
        }).start();
    }
}
```

I hope that I could help.

---

*Have a look [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm) or [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multithreading-in-java/) for nice introductions into multithreading.*

Comment: Thank you for your correction. I copied your answer to replace my original and executed it but I got the same result as before. i.e. It played the music but no visuals at all.

Comment: @Dien After having a second look at the code I think I've found the problem. In ```Test7``` you are building the UI by adding labels, boxes, buttons ans so on. You are initializing the UI there, set it to be visible and make it be displayed. I my answer I though ```MyPanel``` would do that initially but that is not the case. Please make sure that ```new MyPanel().display();``` builds a fully functional and displayed UI.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! you make me so happy! It works now!

Comment: You are welcome. :-) Feel free to upvote and accept the answer. I've put quite some time into it.

Comment: Of course I will give an up-vote, But I don't know how and where to put it.

Answer (score 0):

Now it works by the following:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import java.io.*;
import sun.audio.*;

class AudioTest {
//This class is used to play a section of 1 minute long music
    public void AudioPlay() {

        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

        try{
          Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
          AudioInputStream inputStream = 
AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("audio1.wav"));

              clip.open(inputStream);
              clip.start();
              while (!clip.isRunning())
                  Thread.sleep(0);
              while (clip.isRunning())
                  Thread.sleep(0);
              clip.close();
            } catch (Exception e)
                {
                  e.printStackTrace(); 
                  System.out.println(e); 
                }
        System.out.println("done"); 
    } 
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel{   
    int x[] = new int[59]; 
    int y[] = new int[59]; 
    int width[] = new int[59];
    int height = 20;
    Color color[] = new Color[59];//the color of each note

    //一根紫 竹 直 苗 苗,      5  ĺ  65 3 │ 52 32 1 ─ 
    //送給寶寶做管 簫,      6 ĺ   3 5  6 3 │5 ─ ─ ─
    //簫兒對準口,            ĺ 6 3 6 5 ─ 
    //口兒對準簫,           6 5 3 6  5 ─
    //簫 中吹 出  新 時 調, 56  ĺ  65 3 │ 52 32 1 ─
    //小寶寶, 小寶 寶,      1 13 2 ─  | 1 13 2  ─   
    //咿底 咿底學會了.啊～～  6 ĺ   6  ĺ  2 6 | 5 . 6  23 56│ 5 ─ ─ ─

    String[] lyric = {"一", " 根", "紫～", "竹", "直～", "苗～", "苗,", "送", "給", 
"寶", "寶", "做", "管", "簫,",
                      "簫", "兒", "對", "準", "口,", "口", "兒", "對", "準", "簫,", 
                      "簫～", "中", "吹～", "出", "新～", "時～ ", "調,",
                      "小", "寶～", "寶,", "小", "寶～", "寶,", 
                      "咿", "底", "咿", "底", "學 ", "會", "了,", "啊 ～     ～    
～"};//共45個

    int[] numNotes = {1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1,
                      1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6};//共45個

    int[][] notes = {{5,2},{8,2},{6,1},{5,1},{3,2},{5,1},{2,1},{3,1},{2,1},{1,4}, 
                     {6,1},{8,1},{3,1},{5,1},{6,2},{3,2},{5,8},{8,1},{6,1},{3,1}, 
                     {6,1},{5,4},{6,1},{8,1},{3,1},{6,1},{5,4},{5,1},{6,1},{8,2}, 
                     {6,1},{5,1},{3,2},{5,1},{2,1},{3,1},{2,1},{1,4},{1,2},{1,1}, 
                     {3,1},{2,4},{1,2},{1,1},{3,1},{2,4},{6,1},{8,1},{6,1},{8,1}, 
                     {9,2},{6,2},{5,3},{6,1},{2,1},{3,1},{5,1},{6,1},{5,8}};

    String[] simplifiedNote = {"| 5", "  1", " 6", "5", "3", "| 5", "2", "3", 
                               "2", "1  - ", "| 6", "1", "3", "5", "6", " 3", " 5  
                                -  -  -", "| 1", "6", "3", "6", "5  - ", "| 6", 
                                "1", "3", "6", "5  -", "| 5", "6", "1", "6", "5", 
                                " 3", "| 5", "2", "3", "2", "1   -", "| 1", "1", 
                                "3", "2   -", "| 1", "1", "3", "2  -", "| 6", 1", 
                                "6", "1", "2", "6", "| 5   .", "6", "2", "3", 
                                "5", "6", "| 5  -  -  - "};

    Color color0 = new Color(255,255,255); //白色 
    Color color1 = new Color(255,0,0); //紅色
    Color color2 = new Color(255,165,0); //橙色
    Color color3 = new Color(255,255,0); //黃色
    Color color4 = new Color(0,128,0); //綠色
    Color color5 = new Color(0,0,255); //藍色
    Color color6 = new Color(75,0,130); //靛色
    Color color7 = new Color(100,0,153); //紫色
    Color color8 = new Color(153,0,0); //暗紅
    Color color9 = new Color(0,0,0); //黑色
    Color color10 = new Color(37,255,255); //淺藍

    public void display(){
        for (int i = 0;i < notes.length; i++) {
            //System.out.println("notes[" + i + "][0] = " + notes[i][0]);
            switch (notes[i][0]) {
                case 1:
                     y[i] = 400;
                     color[i] = color1;
                     break;
                case 2:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20;
                     color[i] = color2;
                     break;
                case 3:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*2;
                     color[i] = color3;
                     break;
                case 4:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*3;
                     color[i] = color4;
                     break;
                case 5:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*4;
                     color[i] = color5;
                     break;
                case 6:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*5;
                     color[i] = color6;
                     break;
                case 7:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*6;
                     color[i] = color7;
                     break;
                case 8:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*7;
                     color[i] = color1;
                     break;
                case 9:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*8;
                     color[i] = color2;
            }

            switch (notes[i][1]) {
                case 1: width[i] = 20;     
                        break;
                case 2: width[i] = 20 * 2; 
                        break;
                case 3: width[i] = 20 * 3; 
                        break;
                case 4: width[i] = 20 * 4; 
                        break;
                case 5: width[i] = 20 * 5; 
                        break;
                case 6: width[i] = 20 * 6; 
                        break;
                case 7: width[i] = 20 * 7; 
                        break;
                case 8: width[i] = 20 * 8;
            }
        }

        x[0] = 100;
        for (int i = 1; i < notes.length; i++){
             x[i] = x[i-1] + width[i-1];
        }



        int timeLast = 0; //total executing time

        while(timeLast < 900){ 
            for (int i = 0; i < notes.length; i ++){
                x[i]--;
            }
            this.repaint(); 
            try {Thread.sleep(50);}
            catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            timeLast = timeLast + 1; 
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g); 
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

        g2d.setColor(color9); 
        g2d.setFont(new Font("新細明體", Font.BOLD, 20));

        int y1 = 130; //C調 4/4 Y坐標
        int y2 = 180; //簡譜行Y坐標
        int y3 = 210; //歌詞行Y坐標
        int y4 = 163; //加高音點
        int y5 = 180; //加八分音符底線
        int y6 = 470;  //色彩音符說明

        int chrPosition = 0;
        g2d.drawString("C調  4/4", 16, y1);

        //色彩音符說明
        g2d.drawString("色彩音符：", 16, y6);
        g2d.setColor(color1);

        g2d.fillRoundRect(126, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(": Do", 150, y6);//126 + 24
        g2d.setColor(color2);
        g2d.fillRoundRect(206, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);//150 + 56
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(": Re", 230, y6);//206 + 24
        g2d.setColor(color3);
        g2d.fillRoundRect(286, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);//230 + 56
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(": Mi", 310, y6);//286 + 24
        g2d.setColor(color4);
        g2d.fillRoundRect(366, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);//310 + 56
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(": Fa",390, y6);//366 + 24
        g2d.setColor(color5);
        g2d.fillRoundRect(446, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);//390 + 56
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(": So", 470, y6);//446 + 24
        g2d.setColor(color6);
        g2d.fillRoundRect(526, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);//470 + 56
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(": La", 550, y6);//526 + 24
        //g2d.setColor(color7);
        //g2d.fillRoundRect(606, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);//550 + 56
        //g2d.setColor(color9);
        //g2d.drawString(":Si", 630, y6);//606 + 24

        //寫出簡譜
        for (int i = 0;i < simplifiedNote.length; i++){

            g2d.drawString(simplifiedNote[i], x[i], y2);
        }

        //在簡譜下方寫出歌詞
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        for (int i = 0;  i < lyric.length; i++){
            if (i != 0 && numNotes[i-1] == 2) {
                chrPosition = chrPosition + 1;
                g2d.drawString(lyric[i], x[chrPosition], y3);
            }
            else {
                g2d.drawString(lyric[i], x[chrPosition], y3);
            }
            chrPosition = chrPosition + 1;
        }


        //在簡譜上方加高音點
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[1]+14, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[11]+2, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[17]+11, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[23]+2, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[29]+2, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[47]+2, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[49]+2, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[50]+2, y4);

        //在簡譜下方加八分音符底線
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[2]+4, y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[3], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[5]+8, y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[6], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[7], y5);//5
        g2d.drawString("_", x[8], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[10]+8, y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[11], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[12], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[13], y5);//10
        g2d.drawString("_", x[17]+8, y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[18], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[19], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[20], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[22]+8, y5);//15
        g2d.drawString("_", x[23], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[24], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[25], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[27]+8, y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[28], y5);//20
        g2d.drawString("_", x[30], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[31], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[33]+8, y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[34], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[35], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[36], y5);//25
        g2d.drawString("_", x[39], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[40], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[43], y5);//1
        g2d.drawString("_", x[44], y5);//3
        g2d.drawString("_", x[46]+8, y5);//6
        g2d.drawString("_", x[47], y5);//1
        g2d.drawString("_", x[48], y5);//6
        g2d.drawString("_", x[49], y5);//1
        g2d.drawString("_", x[53], y5);//6
        g2d.drawString("_", x[54], y5);//2
        g2d.drawString("_", x[55], y5);//3
        g2d.drawString("_", x[56], y5);//5
        g2d.drawString("_", x[57], y5);//6

        //在歌詞下方繪出彩色譜        
        for (int i = 0;i < notes.length; i++){

            g2d.setColor(color[i]);
            g2d.fillRoundRect(x[i], y[i], width[i], height, 3,3); //畫圓角方塊

            g2d.setColor(color8);
            g2d.drawLine(x[i],230, x[i]+width[i], 230);//畫水平上線

            g2d.setColor(color8);
            g2d.drawLine(x[i],231, x[i], 429);//畫直紅線

            g2d.setColor(color8);
            g2d.drawLine(x[i],430, x[i]+width[i], 430);//畫水平下線
        }
        g2d.setColor(color8);
        g2d.drawLine(x[notes.length-1]+ width[notes.length - 1],231, x[notes.length - 1] + width[notes.length - 1],429);//畫邊界直紅線
    }
}

 public class Test21 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            JFrame  jf = new JFrame("康樂彩歌");        
            MyPanel jp = new MyPanel();
            //jp.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

            jp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
            jf.setBounds(0, 0, 1368, 730);      
            jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            JLabel label1 = new JLabel("選歌：");    //創建標簽
            label1.setFont(new Font("新細明體", Font.PLAIN, 20));
            JComboBox cmbox = new JComboBox();    //創建JComboBox
            //cmb.setLocation(500,500);
            cmbox.setFont(new Font("新細明體", Font.PLAIN, 20));
            //cmb.setBounds(120,80,150,30);

            cmbox.addItem("紫竹調");
            cmbox.addItem("走一同去郊遊");
            cmbox.addItem("大野狼");
            cmbox.addItem("歸來吧蘇連多");
            cmbox.addItem("追尋");
            cmbox.addItem("三輪車");
            cmbox.addItem("我家門前有小河");
            cmbox.addItem("漁家樂");
            cmbox.addItem("嚕啦啦");
            cmbox.addItem("踏雪尋梅");

            JRadioButton rb2 = new JRadioButton("加人聲", false);
            rb2.setFont(new Font("新細明體", Font.PLAIN, 20));

            JButton btPlay = new JButton("PLAY");
            btPlay.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG_INPUT, Font.BOLD, 25));

            JButton btStop = new JButton("STOP");
            btStop.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG_INPUT, Font.BOLD, 25));

            JButton btContinue = new JButton("CONTINUE");
            btContinue.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG_INPUT, Font.BOLD, 25));

            jp.add(label1);
            jp.add(cmbox);
            //jp.add(rb1);
            jp.add(rb2);
            jp.add(btPlay);
            jp.add(btStop);
            jp.add(btContinue);

            btPlay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                   }
                  });

            jf.setVisible(true);
            jf.add(jp); 
            // Create and start the thread that plays the audio.
            new Thread(() -> {
                new AudioTest().AudioPlay();
            }).start();

            // Create and start the thread that shows the visuals.
            new Thread(() -> {
                jp.display();
            }).start();
    }
}
```